# TypeScript cannot narrow type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics, tsc, conditional-types

### (If you find a better name, please let me know)

I have a function that receives two arguments, a job and an employee. The employee is optional: if the job is scheduled, the employee will be there, otherwise it is not needed.

```
type Job = {
    name: string;
    schedule?: string;
}

type WorkingEmployee = {
    doWork: (jobName: string) => void
}

function f(job: Job, employee?: WorkingEmployee){
    if (job.schedule) {
        if (employee) {
            employe.do(job.name)
        }
    }
}
```

However, I know more than this. I know that, if the job is scheduled, then the employee will be there. So I want to enforce this and take advantage of this knowledge:

```
type ScheduledJob = {
    task: string;
    isDoable: string;
}
type Employee<T> = T extends ScheduledJob ? WorkingEmployee : undefined;

function f<T extends Job>(job: T, employee: Employee<T>){
    if (job.schedule) {
        employee.doWork(job.name);
    }
}
```

But typescript does not take it: `"Object is possibly undefined"`, referring to `employee.doWork`. Why does it not accept it? If `schedule` is there, then we know for certain that `employee` is not `undefined`.

My questions are:
 1. Why the compiler does not accept this code?
 2. Is there any way of achieving what I am trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

Generic types are narrowed down when the function gets called. At the time of definition you only know that `T` is some sort of `Job`. The typeguard will narrow down the type of `job`, it won't change what `T` refers to.

```
 let a: T, b: T;

 if(a.narrow) {
   // a can be narrowed down, but it is unknown wether the same applies to b. Thus T cannot be narrowed.
 }
```

You could overload f though (not sure if that works as intended, however it is clearer than a generic function with conditional types):

```
 function f(job: ScheduledJob, employee: WorkingEmployee);
 function f(job: Job, employee?: WorkingEmployee) {
   //...
 }
```